# How to simulate a key press in an out of focus window

Tags: keyboard, script, autohotkey, simulation

I'm looking for a way to simulate a key press in an out of focus window.

More specifically, I need to press a key every x seconds in a browser page for a given amount of time. It should look like a simple key press while on the webpage without any input field selected.

I'm currently doing this with a simple AHK script, but I can't use the laptop meanwhile because I need to leave the browser's page in focus.

Do you have any ideas about that? Thank you.

edit: 
If it can help, there are two options in this webpage that I can select using the keys "0" and "1", and I would like to be able to select one of them while the window is minimized or in background.

Comment: Doesn't your script work without focus? It would be a good idea to show us this script.

Comment: My original script uses a simple "Send" command. I also tried ControlSend as suggested in the other answer, but it doesn't seem to fit my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

Simulate a key press (send the key "a") in an (out of focus or minimized) notepad window every 2 seconds:

```
Loop
{
    ControlSend,, a, ahk_class Notepad
    Sleep, 2000 ; 2 seconds
}
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm

Instead of Loop you can use [SetTimer](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm).

Comment: I tried this method but it doesn't work. I'll try to be more specific:

in the browser page there are two options that I can select with the keys "0" and "1"; with ControlSend I found that an option is selected only if the windows is in focus.